# SF - high availability options?

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have a greenfield application that I would like to host on Service Fabric but high availability  will be a key concern.  Is there a way for a cluster to span across Azure region’s?   Does Service Fabric recognize Availability Zones?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is there a way for a cluster to span across Azure region’s?

Yes, it's in the [FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-common-questions).

> The core Service Fabric clustering technology can be used to combine
>   machines running anywhere in the world, so long as they have network
>   connectivity to each other. However, building and running such a
>   cluster can be complicated.
>   If you are interested in this scenario, we encourage you to get in
>   contact either through the Service Fabric GitHub Issues List or
>   through your support representative in order to obtain additional
>   guidance. The Service Fabric team is working to provide additional
>   clarity, guidance, and recommendations for this scenario.

2. Does Service Fabric recognize Availability Zones?

Yes, but limited.
Make sure to check out this [example](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-fabric-cluster-templates/tree/master/9-VM-Windows-Cross-AZ-UnSecure) (marked as 'not production ready'). And check out [SF Mesh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric-mesh/service-fabric-mesh-overview) as well, which allows you to deploy to multiple AZ's. (but currently in preview)